# Get dynamic value for AMP html page

Tags: amp-html

I am trying to write simple product listing page.
I need to deal with real time data since product price and quantity changes.
What is the best way to achieve this?

I tried to use `amp-list`, but I have to set up endpoints where I can download `json` data. And it sounds like I need to set up an extra job which updates `json` data constantly.

I think I have to use `iFrame` but I want to make sure if `iFrame` is the only way and there is no workaround.

Is there any workaround or I can use `amp-list` for this purpose?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case i see only [amp-iframe](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-iframe/) as a solution. But iframe is not Google friendly for a product shop.
The best way is to find a solution with JSON and [amp-list](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-list/) or [amp-live-list](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-live-list/)

Answer (score 1):

There is a component called [amp-fresh](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/4191) which may solve your problem but it's still under development. You may want to subscribe to the issue to see if there are any updates.